# How to use global in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global

Im working on a game for Python with turtle. However whenever I make functions the variables inside them are not recognised.

```
morale_points = 0
wall_points = 100

def repair_fort():

        global morale_points
        global wall_points

        if morale_points >= 100 and wall_points <= 80:
            morale_points -= 100
            wall_points += 20
```

Am I using global wrong? If so, is there a better way to accomplish an in-game transaction? Thanks.

error:

name 'morale_points' is not defined

Comment: please check your syntax - you might have a typo or use it elsewhere where NO global was used. Post the full function and the complete stacktrace of your error. Thanks

Comment: As currently shown (after formatting edits), your code example is fine.  What's the issue?